# Virtual Environment Not showing up in VS Code Terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, anaconda, virtual-environment

I was trying to activate a Conda environment from VS Code Terminal. Everything worked but it does not show that it is using the specified Conda Environment. Take a look at my Terminal.[Just PS(no venv)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDqa6.png)

But when I looked at other people's terminal. It is actually showing their environment name in the bracket. Just on a Curious Note, I am asking Why it is so?
[virtual environment name in bracket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRMSE.png)

Comment: How are things going?  Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that "PowerShell" does not activate the conda environment by default.

Solution:
Please use the command

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process
```

in terminal to change the execution policy of "PowerShell", and then open a new VS Code terminal (Ctrl+Shift+`):

[image]

Check: We can view that the "`profile.ps1`" file is generated here.

[image]

Reference: [Conda environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_global-virtual-and-conda-environments).